# What's the part of speech of the noun after 'twice'?

Tags: parts-of-speech

He could earn **twice** *his present salary* at the new job.

**Twice** *two* is four.

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/search/twice) says ‘twice’ followed by a noun is an adverb. In this case, is the noun still called a noun or something else?

Comment: If you mean _salary_, yes, it's still a noun.

Comment: I think *twice* should be called an adjective in these use (as opposed to uses such as **the postman always rings twice**), but dictionaries seem to disagree.

Comment: What about "the postman always rings twice the amount other people ring"?

Comment: What about "we had requests for twice as much money as we received"? What verb does "twice" modify there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The word *twice* is a numeral **[Quantifier](http://www.sil.org/linguistics/GlossaryOfLinguisticTerms/WhatIsAQuantifier.htm)**; it's called an adverb in dictionaries because "adverb" is the traditional wastebasket category -- if you don't know what [the hell](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/thehell.html) it's doing there, call it an adverb.

Quantifiers can be moved around like adverbs, though there are special rules for that (Quantifier-Float}, and they are [Determiners](http://www.sil.org/linguistics/GlossaryOfLinguisticTerms/WhatIsADeterminer.htm) like articles, so they can modify nouns, too.

This particular kind of numeral quantifier (*once, twice, thrice, four times, ... `n` times*) indicates the number of occurrences of some event, and by metaphoric extension, the multiplicative size (note multiplicative *times* in the construction) of any standard measure NP.

In the sentence

- *He will earn twice his present salary.*

*twice* quantifies the Noun Phrase

- *twice his present salary*
  which means 'an amount which equals two times the amount of his present salary'

which is the direct object of *He will earn*.

**Executive Summary**: Don't pay any attention to *"Parts of Speech"*; there's a lot more going on.

Answer (score 2):

1) The word **twice** is **always** an **adverb**.

> twice |twʌɪs| **adverb**
>
> two times;  on two occasions: the earl married
>   twice | the tablets should be taken twice a day. • double in degree or
>   quantity: I'm twice your age | an engine twice as big as the original.

2)**salary** and **two** in the sentences above **always** are **nouns**. You can't twist it and call it something else.

Comment: So adverbs can modify nouns?

Comment: @PeterShor: No. `twice` doesn't modify `salary` here. "[He] [earned twice] [his present salary] ..."

Comment: @David: Yes it does. You wouldn't say "He could earn his present salary twice". If "twice" modified "earn", that would mean the same thing as "earn twice his present salary". And the position of "twice" in the sentence "We will pay you twice your present salary" is one which an adverb modifying "pay" is very uncomfortable taking. Consider *"We will fine you twice $100; on the third offence, the fine is raised to $500.

Comment: According to John Lawler, calling _twice_ an adverb seems to indicate one's analytical skills are in some way connected with a wastebasket. Mind you, I'm surprised he uses the terms 'adverbs' and 'nouns' in what one assumes is a generally recognised way in his second paragraph.

Comment: It's not at all clear whether _twice_ is what the OP is actually asking about. He asks 'is the noun still called a noun or something else?' I answered that in my comment.

Comment: @PeterShor: All of those things are perfectly fine and do mean the same thing. They're just a bit awkward because it's not the standard word order. "He could earn his present salary twice" more likely means two distinct earning events each of his present salary but can mean one event of twice as much. "He could earn twice his current salary" more likely means one earning of a doubled amount but can also mean two earnings of his current salary. They perfectly overlap. In one cases, it is the amount of earning that is doubled, in the other, the number of earnings.